# Why can not I get the html loaded by .load() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is:

```
<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <button>click me</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("<div></div>").load("1.html").appendTo($("#main"));
        alert($("li").length);
        $("button").click(function() {
            alert($("li").length);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

And the 1.html:

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
</ul>
```

At first it alerts 0;But when i click the button, it alerts 5.Why?
And how can I get the number of li when at the first alert window?

Comment: Did you read the documentation, `load` inserts the content automagically for you, it looks like you really want to use `$.get` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `.load()` is asynchronous, which means that when the `.load()` has fired the script you have continues to execute thus alerting `0`.
But when you click the load is most likely finished and then you'll get the correct length.

To fix this, use the callback that you can provide to `load()` which will be executed when the call has finished.

```
$('<div></div>').load('1.html', function(data) {
    alert($("li").length);
});
```

Comment: Now I have another question. If there are five html files, 0.html, 1.html, ..., 4.html, how can I get the number of the lis when all these files be loaded?